# How to use VST3 plugin inside NET Application

Tags: c#, c++, naudio, vst, naudio-framework

I have NET application with input device and output device..

Now I have a VST3 plugin (speechextraction.vst3), and I need use this plugin (as affection) to take wave sound from input device and give wave to output device..

But How can I do in my application (Use VST.NET or wrapper VST3 SKD), and I need flow to work with VST3 plugin...

Please give me some advise or sample about that

Comment: What have you tried so far? Vst3 looks like a native dll, so you would need to use PInvoke or other interoperability methods to use it, or find a .Net wrapper.

Comment: A VST3 dll has an unmanaged entry point function that gives you a plugin factory (interface). The VST3 interfaces are all COM compatible, so you could try DllImport on the .vst3 (dll) and use .NET COM-interop to talk to the plugin.
VST.NET does not currently support VST3 (working on it), but you can look at it for 'inspiration' (Source3 folder). [2c]

Comment: So, what can i do with file *.vst3 (not dll extension)

Comment: .vst3 is a renamed .dll - it's the same.

Comment: Thanks!, Are you have any samples about it, a need only load vst file, and run process function to convert audio in event of NAudio?